# TestLink 1.9.14 Installation

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver, testlink

i installed **wampserver 3.0.4** (php 7.0.4 and mysql 5.7.11) so that i could install TestLink 1.9.14, but after the installation, when i should log in for the first time to the application, i find this error message:

[image]

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\testlink
>   1.9.14\testlink-1.9.14\third_party\adodb\drivers\adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 364

i tried many things but nothing worked, do you have any idea of where can be that function declared or if any library is needed? I have read that it could be necessary to connect using PDO, in that case, how could i do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `MYSQL_` API has been removed from PHP7 **Gone for ever**.

Switch to the other version of PHP in order to run this code you have installed

Using the wampmanager icon in the system tray do

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> Version -> 5.7.11
```

Wait for WAMPServer to restart Apache, which it will do automatically.

This older version of PHP still has the `mysql_` API

Comment: Was this no help? If not I will delete it

Comment: Hi Riggs, I finally unistalled wamp and installed testlink via Bitnami and it worked fine. Thank you very much for your answer!